# Patternmatching sets

Tags: programming, pattern-matching, sets

**How to match set-patterns against sets?**

A set (in the mathematical sense) is a list of elements without repetition and order of elements does not matter. For example, we have a pattern set `{3, 1}` that should match sets `{1, 3}`, `{1, 2, 3}`, `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and so on. Note, that the list-length of the pattern is not relevant: any set that contains elements 3 and 1 should match the pattern. So far, this is simple subset testing - but there are two problems:

1. Since order **does** matter for the patternmatcher, one has to write e.g. `Cases[sets, {___, 3, ___, 1, ____}|{___, 1, ___, 3, ____}]` which causes a combinatorial expansion for an increasing number of element-wise matches. Thus I used `MemberQ` instead of structural patterns.
2. I would like to use more complicated patterns, like: "Find all sets that contain 1 and 3 but not 2!".

I have a working solution, but it is neither effective nor elegant in my opinion. It involves a Boolean description of the pattern (`And` to include all listed elements, `Or` to include any listed element, `Not` to exclude an element), but I am not sure it is the right way to do it. The function simply wraps each element that apperas in the pattern into `MemberQ`, so the Boolean expression translates to a logical combination of `MemberQ` and `Not@MemberQ` calls.

```
setCases[sets_List, patt_] := Module[{elem = Union @@ sets},
   Cases[sets, _?((patt /. x_ /; MemberQ[elem, x] :> MemberQ[#, x]) &), {1}]
   ];
```

Define a list of sets, and a list of patterns for testing:

```
sets = Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4}];

patterns = {1, \[Not] 1, 1 \[And] \[Not] 2, 1 \[Or] \[Not] 2, 
   1 \[Or] 2 \[Or] 3, 1 \[And] 2 \[And] 3, 
   1 \[And] \[Not] 2 \[And] \[Not] 3, 1 \[Or] (2 \[And] \[Not] 3), 
   1 \[And] \[Not] (2 \[And] 3), 1 \[And] \[Not] (2 \[Or] 3), 
   1 \[And] \[Not] (2 \[Or] (3 \[And] \[Not] 4)),
   \[Not] 1 \[And] \[Not] 2 \[And] \[Not] 3 \[And] \[Not] 4}

Grid[{#, setCases[sets, #]} & /@ patterns, Alignment -> Left, 
 Background -> {None, {{LightGray, White}}}, Spacings -> {1, 1}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's examine one case closer, by displaying the ultimate pattern that is tested:

```
(1 \[Or] 2) \[And] \[Not] 3 /. x_Integer :> MemberQ[#, x]
```

> ```
> (MemberQ[#1, 1] & || (MemberQ[#1, 2] &)) && ! (MemberQ[#1, 3] &)
> ```

As one can see, the function is far from being economic: alternatives could have been gathered under one `MemberQ` (`MemberQ[#, 1]& || MemberQ[#, 2]&` is equivalent to `MemberQ[#, 1|2]&`) and I think that `Except` should be used as well, though have no idea how. I am interested in robust, fast solutions.

**Note**: Do NOT try to simplify the logical patterns, as:

```
Simplify[And[1, 2]] ==> 2
Simplify[And[0, 1]] ==> False
```

Comment: @Leonid Actually, I've found a case where *Mathematica* uses a similar approach. Check the **Details** under [`TextSearch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextSearch.html). It uses `List` for `And`, `Alternatives` for `Or` and `Except` for `Not`. According to `PrintDefinitions` spelunking, there is a full-blown query-set-algebra, check e.g. `TextSearch^IndexSearch^PackagePrivate^compileQuery` and `...^exec`: `QNot`, `QUnion`, `QIntersection`, `QComplement`, `QString` are the specific functions. (backticks are replaced by `^`)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @Istvan. I will definitely look it up. These things interest me a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### A main idea of a pattern-based solution

I don't know why we should make life so complicated, since you can always use things like `Intersection` and `Complement` to test whether a given set is a subset of another set. But if you want to use the pattern-matcher, here is one option:

```
ClearAll[set];
SetAttributes[set, {Orderless, Flat, OneIdentity}];

ClearAll[setCasesLS]
setCasesLS[sets : {__List}, patt_] :=
   List @@@ Cases[set @@@ sets, patt];
```

Now, for example:

```
setCasesLS[sets, set[1,__]]

(*  {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}  *)

setCasesLS[sets,set[1,Except[2|set[3 ,Except[4]]]...]]

(* {{1},{1,3},{1,4},{1,3,4}}  *)
```

It may be an interesting sub-problem to to translate your specs into the patterns used here (involving `Except` etc), but at least conceptually this could be a valid starting point.

#### Pattern translator (a sketch, may contain errors)

Ok, it seems that I was able to write a pattern translator which translates your patterns into those which can be used with `setCasesLS`. But the code is long and ugly, and I would not  be suprised if it won't work in more complicated cases. Anyway, here goes:

This is a set of preprocessing functions:

```
ClearAll[or, and, not];
SetAttributes[{or, and}, {Flat, OneIdentity}];
or[left : Except[_not] ..., x_not, y : Except[_not], rest___] :=
   or[left, y, x, rest];
and[left : Except[_not] ..., x_not, y : Except[_not], rest___] :=
   and[left, y, x, rest];
and[not[x_], not[y_]] /; FreeQ[{x, y}, _not] := not[or[x, y]];
not[not[x_]] := x;
not[and[x_, y_]] := or[not[x], not[y]];
and[left___, or[not[x_], y___], right___] :=
   or[and[left, not[x], right], and[left, y, right]];

Clear[process];
process[expr_] :=  expr /. {And -> and, Not -> not, Or -> or}
```

Here is a pattern converter:

```
ClearAll[convert];
convert[HoldPattern[pattern[or[simple : Except[_not | _and] .., rest___]]]] :=
   Alternatives[
     set[Alternatives @@ simple, ___],
     Sequence @@ convert[pattern[or[rest]]]
   ];
convert[HoldPattern[pattern[or[args___]]]] :=
    Alternatives @@ 
        Map[
          If[MatchQ[#, _not], set[convert[#]], convert[pattern[#]]] &, 
          {args}
        ];
convert[HoldPattern[pattern[and[args : Except[_not] ..]]]] :=
   set @@ Append[Map[convert, {args}], ___];
convert[HoldPattern[pattern[and[args___]]]] :=
   set @@ Map[convert, {args}];
convert[HoldPattern[pattern[not[x_]]]] := Except[convert[pattern@x]];
convert[HoldPattern[not[x_]]] := Except[convert[x]] ...;
convert[HoldPattern[or[args___]]] := Alternatives[args];
convert[pattern[x_]] := set[x, ___];
convert[x_] := x;
```

and this is a main function to bring it all together:

```
ClearAll[fullConvert];
fullConvert[patt_] :=
  With[{res = convert@pattern@process@patt},
     res /; FreeQ[res, not | and | or]
  ];
fullConvert[patt_] :=
  With[{res = convert@pattern@not@process@Not@patt},
     res /; FreeQ[res, not | and | or]
  ];
fullConvert[patt_] := $Failed;
```

If it does not succeed in converting a direct pattern, it attempts to convert a negated one. If that also fails, it returns `$Failed`.

Here is how this works on your patterns:

```
fullConvert/@patterns
```

> ```
> {
>     set[1,___],
>     Except[set[1,___]],
>     set[1,Except[2]...],
>     set[1,___]|set[Except[2]...],
>     set[1,___]|set[2,___]|set[3,___],
>     set[1,2,3,___],
>     set[1,Except[2|3]...],
>     set[1,___]|set[2,Except[3]...],
>     set[1,Except[3]...]|set[1,Except[2]...],
>     set[1,Except[2|3]...],
>     Except[set[2,___]|set[3,Except[4]...]|set[Except[1]...]],
>     Except[set[1,___]|set[4,___]|set[2,___]|set[3,___]]
>  }
> ```

If you now execute

```
 setCasesLS[sets, fullConvert[#]]} & /@ patterns
```

you get the results identical to yours.

I actually think that I am missing some simplificatins which would make the above code shorter, more general and more robust at the same time, but the current solution still seems interesting enough to post it.

Comment: You know how it is... After 3 days of intensive brainstorming you close in on the core of your problem. And that is the point where you won't see the wood from the tree.

Comment: To answer your Q about the complicatedness of life in general: in my case I refrained to use `Union`, `Intersection` and `Complement` because I inject the sets later into placeholders which are not sets themselves, thus functions like `Union` must be hold. Instead of holding, I went the other way.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Actually, I changed my mind after reading the question more carefully, for more complex patterns of the type you ask for we may benefit from something else than `Complement` and `Intersection` - such as pattern-matcher. Working on an automatic translator from your patterns to the ones I use here...

Comment: Actually, @IstvánZachar, there are some ambiguities in the patterns. For example, what do you mean by "And" (`&&`)? I currently interpret `1 && 2` as a requirement that at both `1` and `2` should be present in the subset at least once - but this is obviously not how you interpret it (otherwise the pattern `!1 && !2 && !3 && !4` should match all the subsets). Also, can you explain e.g. what is the meaning of `1 && 2 && 3`?  Again, I currently interpret this as a requirement that the subset should have all these elements, but from your results, this is obviously not how you interpret this.

Comment: Yes, you are right: my examples are wrong, I intended to use `And` and `Or` the way you have interpreted them. I lost my solution somewhere in the process of development. Checking now...

Comment: Ha! The late addition `Simplify` was the problem: apparently, `Simplify[And[1,2]]` simplifies to 2. I didn't know that 0/1 booleans are handled this way!

Comment: @IstvánZachar I analyzed the current setup and came to a conclusion that your pattern language is ambiguous because it is underspecified. What you need is to introduce two new quantors: `exists` and `for all`. Then, your logical operators such as `Not` or `Identity` will be applied to these. *Then*, there will be no ambiguities left.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis and the answer Leonid! Could you please detail a case where my approach becomes ambiguous? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I am still into it. I still want to write an automatic translator of patterns. As to your current setup, I think it is probably ok, if we interpret `Not` as *not for all elements* (so, `!2` means "there is no single `2` among the elements"), but certain things are currently impossible to express. For example, I may wish all subsets where there is at least one element which is not `2` (but I don't require all of them to be not `2`).

Comment: I see! Yes, that makes sense, and I did not think of this as my use-case is much more limited than the full potential of your predicate logic. The less powerfull zeroth-order logic is fine with me.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Yes, sure. It is just that it makes it harder to write an automatic pattern converter.But I am on my way ...

Comment: I am intrigued as to how you are tweaking his specifications. I am under the impression, without giving it deep thought, that specifications using `set` like yours are quite straighforward, so quite similar to any reasonable specifications that come to mind.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I added an ugly first version of a pattern translator. I am sure that I am missing something simple here, but can't think clearly any more today, so posted as is.

Comment: @Rojo Have a look at my update. It is pretty ugly, and I have a hunch that I am missing something very simple, but posted nonetheless.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, what about... Humm, too big for a comment, posting as answer

Comment: Why use the attribute `OneIdentity`? The set `{x}` which contains the sole element `x` is not the same as the object `x` itself.

Comment: @becko It is more complicated than that. `OneIdentity` works on the level of pattern-matching, not literally converting `{x}` to `x`. Usually, `Flat` and `OneIdentity` go together. Giving some symbol one attribute but not the other may result in some really weird stuff. I don't quite remember why I used it in this particular place, and have no time right now to look closer at this, but chances are that I had some reason to do this. You can read more on the relation between `Flat` and `OneIdentity` in David Wagner's book, and also in a number of Mathgroup threads.

Answer (score 5):

This is just to give `set` the proper attributes and make it simplify double `___` and `__`

```
ClearAll[set];
set[a___, Verbatim[___], Verbatim[___] .., b___] := set[a, ___, b];
set[a___, Verbatim[__], Verbatim[__] .., Verbatim[___] ..., b___] := 
  set[a, __, b];
SetAttributes[set, {Orderless, Flat, OneIdentity}];
```

The patterns will be a boolean function of `subset[el1, el2, el3...]`, with the possibility of mixing patterns, so `Except[subset[1,2]]` would represent any subset that is not `subset[1,2]`, and `subset[1, 3,  _]` would represent any subset with 1, 3, and any other element.

```
forms = {"DNF", "CNF",  "AND", "OR"};

convertPattern[patt_, 
  type : (Alternatives @@ forms | Automatic) : Automatic] := 
 With[{pat = BooleanMinimize[patt, type]}, 
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{And, Or}, SetAttributes[{And, Or}, Orderless]; 
   ClearAttributes[{And, Or}, Flat]; And[patt] //. convertionRules]]

convertionRules = {
   And[a___, b : (\[Not] _) .. // Longest] :> 
    Except[Alternatives[b]~Thread~Not // First, And[a]],
   And[a_subset, b__subset, rest___ // Shortest] :> 
    And[set @@ 
      Append[List @@@ Unevaluated@leastCommonElements[a, b], ___], 
     rest],
   (subset | And)[a___] :> set[a, ___], Or -> Alternatives,
   Not -> Except,
   Verbatim[Alternatives][a_] :> a};

(*Thanks @rm-rf*)
leastCommonElements[lists___List] := 
 Join @@ Composition[Last, Sort] /@ 
   GatherBy[Join @@ Gather /@ {lists}, First]
```

So given

```
patterns = {1, \[Not] 1, 1 \[And] \[Not] 2, 1 \[Or] \[Not] 2, 
  1 \[Or] 2 \[Or] 3, 1 \[And] 2 \[And] 3, 
  1 \[And] \[Not] 2 \[And] \[Not] 3, 1 \[Or] (2 \[And] \[Not] 3), 
  1 \[And] \[Not] (2 \[And] 3), 1 \[And] \[Not] (2 \[Or] 3), 
  1 \[And] \[Not] (2 \[Or] (3 \[And] \[Not] 4)), \[Not] 
    1 \[And] \[Not] 2 \[And] \[Not] 3 \[And] \[Not] 4}

sets = Subsets[Range[6]];
```

To translate your patterns to our form we just need to wrap the integers in `subset`, if I understood correctly

```
newPatterns = patterns /. i_Integer :> subset[i]
```

Now, we can see the patterns converted

```
Table[{patterns, convertPattern[#, form] & /@ (newPatterns)}\[Transpose] // 
  TableForm , {form, forms}]
```

Finally, we can test it

```
Cases[set @@@ sets, convertPattern[#]]&/@newPatterns/.set->List//Column
```

Comment: Looks like I won't have time to look at this today, but I will surely do as soon as I have time, and +1 in advance :)

Comment: I just realized you hit 20k without me saying anything: congratulations!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks :), now go get the 50k

Answer (score 1):

This solution is in the same spirit as your approach:

```
Clear@findSets
findSets[list_, all_, any_, none_] := Block[{set},
    SetAttributes[set, {Flat, Orderless}];
    Select[set @@@ list, 
        Function[s,
            !FreeQ[s, set @@ all] &&
            Or @@ (! FreeQ[s, set@#] & /@ any /. {} -> True) &&        
            And @@ (FreeQ[s, set@#] & /@ none)
        ]
   ] /. set -> List
]
```

Use an empty set if you're not specifying anything. You can also use default values of `{}` or convert the arguments to options such as `Any -> {1,2}, All -> {3}, None -> {4}` if that's easier to read. Here's an example usage:

```
l = Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4}];
findSets[l, {2}, {3}, {}]
(* {{2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}} *)

findSets[l, {1, 2}, {}, {4}]
(* {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}} *)

findSets[l, {1}, {2, 4}, {3}]
(* {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 2, 4}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

### [OrderlessPatternSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html)

Using the first four patterns (`{1, ¬ 1, 1 ∧ ¬ 2, 1 ∨ ¬ 2}` ) from Istvan's table:

```
Pick[sets, MatchQ[{OrderlessPatternSequence[___, 1, ___]}] /@ sets]
```

> {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}

```
Pick[sets, MatchQ[Except@{OrderlessPatternSequence[___, 1, ___]}] /@ sets]
```

> {{}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}}

```
Pick[sets, MatchQ[Except[{OrderlessPatternSequence[___, 2, ___]},
    {OrderlessPatternSequence[___, 1, ___]}]] /@ sets]
```

> {{1}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 3, 4}}

```
Pick[sets, MatchQ[Except[{OrderlessPatternSequence[___,  2, ___]}] | 
  {OrderlessPatternSequence[___, 1, ___]}] /@ sets]
```

> {{}, {1}, {3}, {4}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, 
>        {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}