# Simplify assumes Boolean 1 and 0 in logical expressions

Tags: boolean-computation, simplifying-expressions

Per [this chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8139812#8139812) and this [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19692/89) where I encountered the strange behaviour:

```
Simplify[1]          ==> 1       
And[0, 1]            ==> 0 && 1
Simplify[And[2, 3]]  ==> 2 && 3
Simplify[Not[0]]     ==> !0
FullSimplify[Not[0]] ==> True   (* expected !0, thanks Jens *)
Simplify[And[0, 1]]  ==> False   (* expected 0 && 1 *)
Simplify[And[1, 2]]  ==> 2       (* expected 1 && 2 *)
Simplify[Or[0, 1]]   ==> True    (* expected 0 || 1 *)
```

`Simplify` and `Fullsimplify` assume `0 -> False, 1 -> True` in some logical expressions. Only `Or` and `And` are affected but not `Not`. This is certainly undocumented (or underdocumented), and I would say rather inconsistent. Please decide on whether it is a bug or not.

Present in versions 8 and 9 but not in version 7 (or before).

Comment: Simplify@And[6, 4] doesn't "simplify"

Comment: @belisarius It seems to consider `1 == True`, `0 == False`, but the rest of the integers are just numbers.  It's not like in C where `2` would be interpreted as "true" too.  This is why `1 && 2 --> 2` and not `True`.  It's like `True && 2` or `True && expr`.

Comment: If not a bug, it certainly sounds like a "mis-feature". Surely this behavior was bound to cause someone problems sooner or later, especially being undocumented...

Comment: Could be that some sort of inverse of Boole got into the default TransformationFunctions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because `Simplify` converts the expression to a `BooleanFunction` representation. Checking the documentation for `BooleanFunction` you find that:

> Elements of both inputs and outputs can be specified either as True
>   and False or as 1 and 0.

Comment: Wow. This is still scary. But then why does it not return `True` for `Simplify[Not[0]]`?

Comment: @IstvánZachar, looking at the `Trace` output, it seems that `Not[0]` doesn't get converted to a `BooleanFunction`. With the `And[1,2]` example there were heaps of calls to functions in ``System`BooleanDump`` and ``DiscreteMath`DecisionDiagram`` contexts, causing the conversion I mentioned. There was none of that for `Not[0]`. I agree this is scary, it makes for very inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: @IstvánZachar But `FullSimplify[Not[0]]` does return `True` -- "fortunately." Maybe better use `FullSimplify` for more consistency.

Comment: Sounds like the final outcome may not be intentional, just a side effect of how `BooleanFunction` works.  @István Perhaps it worth letting support know about it in case it wasn't intentional.  This sort of undocumented behaviour is not what one would hope to bump into.

Answer (score 4):

Technical Support responded:

> "[Developers] mentioned to me that indeed it is the case that `BooleanFunction`
>   treats 1 as `True` and 0 as `False`, and these "simplifications" occur
>   only when the expression is converted to `BooleanFunction` format.
>
> If any changes to the documentation or these boolean operators I will
>   certainly let you know."

From this I assume that this is known and it is the expected behaviour. I also assume, that if anything changes in the future that most likely will be the Documentation and not the behaviour.