# Remove redundant dependencies from a directed acyclic graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given a directed acyclic graph, I want to remove all the edges $v_i \rightarrow v_j$ if $v_j$ is reachable from $v_i$ by some other path. Given the rich set of graph algorithms in *Mathematica*, what is the best way to achive this?

The background of the problem is this. I have a list of jobs and their dependencies, e.g., $a \rightarrow b$ means job $b$ can start only when job $a$ finishes. A list $\{a \rightarrow b, b \rightarrow c, a \rightarrow c\}$ is redundant because $a \rightarrow c$ is implied. I want to reduce the dependencies to a bare minimum.

Comment: Algorithms I've looked at: minimum spanning tree, edge/vertex cover, shortest paths. But they are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Including working code and showing what you already tried and what your input/output should look like will improve your chances to get an answer and make this question more useful for future visitors. At the moment there is about no *Mathematica* reference, too.

Comment: The solutions people have contributed are all of the "roll your own" type. It's a pity the rich set of graph algorithms in _Mathematica_ are left unutilized for this question while we start from scratch.

Comment: The action that does this is called Transitive Reduction, explained in detail at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of the graph to be reduced. $A$ is also the reachability matrix for 1 hop, and $A^2$ for 2 hops and so on, if we substitue logical and ($\land$) for multiplication and logical or ($\lor$) for addition in multiplying two matrices. $A^k$ ($k<n$) will eventually be all zeros because we cannot have a path of $n$ hops or more where $n$ is the number of vertices (assuming no cycles).

Let $S = A^2 \lor A^3 \lor \cdots \lor A^k$ be the reachability matrix of 2 or more hops. To reduce $A$, we need to remove $i \rightarrow j$ in $A$ if it is also in $S$. The reduced adjacency matrix is therefore $A \land \lnot S$.

To put the above into code, note that we can just use normal multiplication and addition, after all, if we only look at the sign. This has a huge performance boost because we will be using highly optimized matrix multiplications on machine integers. We'll use `Unitize` to keep the intermediate results within the range of machine intergers:

```
reduce[a_] := a (1 - FixedPoint[Unitize[a.(a + #)] &, a.a])
```

Comment: Neatly compacted! This seems to be 2x faster than my code working directly on `Graph`s, you should consider accepting your own answer :)

Answer (score 7):

I do not have experience with graphs and built-in functions related to them, but maybe something based on fact that the following is a `Tautology`:

$(a\Rightarrow b)\land (b\Rightarrow c)\Rightarrow (a\Rightarrow c)$

```
 And[Implies[a, b], Implies[b, c]]~Implies~Implies[a, c] // Simplify
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Edit** I've added temporary replacement for `1` and `0` which can cause a problems since they are interpreted by `Simplify` as `True` and `False`. More there: [Simplify assumes..](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19700/5478)

```
list = {DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[b, c], DirectedEdge[a, c]}; 

reduce[list_] := Module[{a, b}, With[{impl = Implies @@@ list /. {1 -> a, 0 -> b}},
     DirectedEdge @@@ MapIndexed[
                         If[TrueQ @ Simplify @ Implies[And @@ Drop[impl, #2], #1], 
                            Unevaluated[Sequence[]], #1] &
                         , impl]
                       ] /. {a -> 1, b -> 0}]

reduce[list]
```

> ```
> {DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[b, c]}
> ```

#### Edit by m_goldberg

I  think it is is worth looking at some graphs a little more complex than the one the OP mentioned, both before and after `reduce` is applied to them.

```
dag2 = DirectedEdge @@@ {{a, b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {e, b}, {e, c}};
dag3 = DirectedEdge @@@ {{a, b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {e, b}, {e, c}, {e, f}, {f, c}};
dag4 = DirectedEdge @@@ {{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 1}, 
                         {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}}; (*István's example*)


dags = {#, reduce[#]} & /@ {dag2, dag3, dag4}
gridData = Prepend[
             Map[Graph[#, VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"] &,
                 dags, {2}], 
             {"Before", "After"}];
Grid[gridData, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I think it does work well. I had to do some testing with a couple of more interesting data sets to convince myself of it. Since I had the test notebook at hand, I thought *why not post the tests as an illustration of the method?*

Comment: @m_goldberg good idea, feel free to edit it whenever you want.

Comment: Thanks Kuba for the clever idea of reformulating the problem using the language of logic. Along the same lines I got the following: reduce2[list_] := 
 With[{impl = And @@ (list /. DirectedEdge -> Implies)}, 
  List @@ BooleanMinimize[impl, "CNF"] /. {! a_ || b_ :> 
     DirectedEdge[a, b], b_ || ! a_ :> DirectedEdge[a, b]}]

Comment: I was actually looking for graph-specific algorithms.  This detour to the logic method is very refreshing indeed. But there must be a graph algorithm to it, too?

Comment: @asterix314 I'm glad you find it useful. To make it even more compact you can write `Implies @@@ list` instead of `list /. DirectedEdge->Implies`. I used this because I'm not experienced with Graphs. So maybe better hold on with an accept to not discourage others in finding quicker way :)

Answer (score 6):

I used [this generator algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-to-generate-random-directed-acyclic-graphs) for DAGs (by Szabolcs):

```
{vertices, edges} = {7, 10};
elems = RandomSample@PadRight[ConstantArray[1, edges], vertices (vertices-1)/2];
adj = Take[FoldList[RotateLeft, elems, Range[0, vertices-2]], All, 
           vertices]~LowerTriangularize~-1;
g = AdjacencyGraph[adj, DirectedEdges -> True];
EdgeList@g
```

> ```
> {2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 1, 5 -> 2, 5 -> 3, 5 -> 4}
> ```

Removing redundant edges iteratively:

```
new = Graph[Flatten[If[GraphDistance[EdgeDelete[g, #], First@#, 
            Last@#] < Infinity, {}, #] & /@ EdgeList@g], 
         VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10];
Row@{HighlightGraph[g, new, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10], new}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For some graphs, the remaining graph is simply the path graph of the topologically sorted vertices:

```
g = Graph[{2->1, 3->1, 3->2, 4->1, 4->2, 4->3, 5->1, 5->2, 5->3, 5->4}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that this method removes unconnected singletons.

---

### Adjacency matrix version

Here is a version that works directly on adjacency matrices. This should be faster than working on huge `Graph` objects directly.

The `removableQ` function recursively tests if the node `from` has an alternative route to `to` than the direct one, by collecting children nodes. The moment the function finds another edge terminating at `to`, exits from the loop, as it is unnecessary to check further.

```
removableQ[m_, {from_, to_}] := Module[{children},
   children = Flatten@Position[m[[from]], 1];
   If[MemberQ[children, to], Throw@to, 
    Do[removableQ[m, {i, to}], {i, children}]; None]
   ];
```

The wrapper `reduce` iterates through all edges in the matrix:

```
reduce[adj_] := Module[{edgeList = Position[adj, 1], rem},
   rem = DeleteCases[{First@#, 
        Catch@removableQ[ReplacePart[adj, # -> 0], #]} & /@ 
      edgeList, {_, None}];
   ReplacePart[adj, Thread[rem -> 0]]
   ];
```

Let's call `reduce` on a random DAG's adjecency matrix:

```
g = DirectedGraph[RandomGraph[{6, 10}], "Acyclic"];
EdgeList@g
```

> ```
> {1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 6, 5 -> 6}
> ```

```
adj = Normal@AdjacencyMatrix@g
new = reduce@adj;
Row@{g, AdjacencyGraph@new}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that this method does not remove unconnected singletons.

Comment: Strange, my `reduce` drops `1` and leaves `5->4->3->2` for the last case of yours.

Comment: @Kuba It should keep 1. I still cannot figure out whether there is always one exact reduction or it could depend on the order edges are removed.

Comment: @Kuba It removes the 1 because `Simplify@Implies[(3 => 1) && (3 => 2), 2 => 1]` returns `True`, though it shouldn't for a graph (if you have edges `3->1` and `3->2` you don't necessarily have `2->1`)!

Comment: Or rather pay attention to `1` an `0` which are interpreted by logical functions ;) `Implies["a", 1] // Simplify`

Comment: @Kuba Oh, sure, that [buglike feature](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19700/89) got me once. Quite annoying!

Comment: I'm going to accept this for now as it wins in terms of performance. The run time of @Kubma's Simplfy-based algorithm is quite intractable when the number of edges gets large, say 100.

Comment: @asterix314 Yes, `Simplify` could be a huge bottleneck. If you really have to work on huge graphs, I'll try to come up with a more direct approach that only uses adjacency matrices. That could be a few magnitudes faster than working on `Graph` objects. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: Here is a more concise formulation based on @IstvánZachar's method: Let A be the adjacency matrix of the original graph. A represents also the single hop reachablility, and A^k for k hops, etc. Here we use And for Times and Or for Plus. The reachability matrix of more than 1 hop is thus S = A^2 + A^3 + ... + A^(n-1). The reduced adjacency matrix is thus And[A, !S]. Or in code:

reduce2[x_] := 
Block[{CenterDot = Function[{a, b}, Inner[BitAnd, a, b, BitOr]]}, 
 BitAnd[x, 1 - BitOr @@ Drop[FixedPointList[CenterDot[#, x] &, CenterDot[x, x], -2]]]]

Comment: @asterix314 Nice solution, I think you should make that an individual answer! Just to note, the last argument (-2) for `FixedPointList` doesn't seem to work on my machine, drops error messages. Without it the code is fine.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Sorry the -2 is for Drop[] actually, because the last 2 elements in the FixedPointList[] are all 0s. Without the Drop the code should also work though. It is worth mentioning that the run time of this concise solution is not so good as yours.

Comment: @asterix314 Still I suggest to put it up as an answer as it is really concise and reflects the nice synergies of matrix operations on graphs.

Comment: OK I'll put it up later after I learn some formating basics ...

Comment: @asterix314 you don't need to define your dot with Inner. You could do the following and it makes code much faster with sparse array: reduce3[x_] := 
 BitAnd[x, 
  1 - BitOr @@ 
    Drop[FixedPointList[Unitize[Dot[#1, x]] &, 
      Unitize[Dot[x, x]]], -2]]

Comment: @halmir yes exactly. See my answer. I got rid of all logical operations (I didn't know `Unitize` so i used `Sign` instead).

Answer (score 3):

**TransitiveReductionGraph** (version 10+)

Using the examples from @Kuba's answer:

```
dag1 = {DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[b, c], DirectedEdge[a, c]};
dag2 = DirectedEdge @@@ {{a, b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {e, b}, {e, c}};
dag3 = DirectedEdge @@@ {{a, b}, {b, c}, {a, c}, {e, b}, {e, c}, {e,  f}, {f, c}};
dag4 = DirectedEdge @@@ {{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3},
  {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}};
options = {VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Large, ImageSize -> Small}
    
Grid[Prepend[Through[{Graph[#, options]&, TransitiveReductionGraph[#, options]&}@#] & /@ 
  {dag1, dag2, dag3, dag4},
 {Style["g", 16, Bold], Style["TransitiveReductionGraph[g]", 16, Bold] }],
 Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.3], Scaled[.3]}, {Scaled[.1], 5, 5, 5, 5}}]
```

[image]

**Note:** Although it works as expected in the cases considered here, as noted by Szabolcs, `TransitiveReductionGraph` [had unresolved issues before version 12.1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83852/question-about-transitivereductiongraph).

Comment: Note that [`TransitiveReductionGraph` is buggy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83852/12) and often returns wrong results.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you; added a note re the bug.

Comment: @kglr: Is the bug problem with `TransitiveReductionGrap` solved in version 13.1 version?

Comment: @kglr: In this link `https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83852/60365`, it says that the problem is solved, but I am not sure if it is really solved!