# Question about TransitiveReductionGraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 12.1** 

*`TransitiveReductionGraph` is new in 10.0.*

---

In Mathematica **10.0** and **10.1**, according to the documentation of [`TransitiveReductionGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransitiveReductionGraph.html):

> The transitive reduction *h* of a graph *g* is a graph that has the same transitive closure as *g*, with a **minimal number of edges**.

But please look at the following example:

```
g = Graph[
        {1 -> 4, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4},
        VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[.2], 
        GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"
        ]
```

[image: original graph g]

The transitive reduction of `g` given by `TransitiveReductionGraph` is `g` itself:

```
mmaTRG =
    TransitiveReductionGraph[g,
        VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[.2], 
        GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"
        ]
```

[image: transitive reduction of g given by MMA]

But apparently there is a graph with less number of edges which has the same transitive closure as `g`:

```
betterTRG =
    Graph[Range[4], {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4},
        VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[6], 
        GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"
        ]
```

[image: the true transitive reduction of g]

```
FindGraphIsomorphism @@ (
            TransitiveClosureGraph /@ {mmaTRG, betterTRG}
            ) // Column
```

> ```
> <| 1 -> 1, 4 -> 4, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3 |>
> ```

So why does Mathematica gives `mmaTRG` while `betterTRG` seems to be the true solution?

Or maybe I misunderstand the documentation and/or the concept of [transitive reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction)?

#### Update:

As more than one user suspect this to be a bug of `TransitiveReductionGraph`, I have reported it to WRI. The case ID is **3345230**.

#### Update 2:

The Wolfram Technical Support has confirmed it as "a known issue", but no workaround is given.

Comment: Smaller counter-example: `g = Graph[{1 -> 4, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4}]`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2 . I found it too but hesitated to upload two new images. But now let me update my post.

Comment: I think it's a bug.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have the same suspicion, but let's see if someone insider can give some more information. In the mean time I'm going to report it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Already reported. Please see the update at the end of the post.

Comment: @Silvia Great, thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this bug has been known to Wolfram for nearly 3 years, yet very disappointingly it is still unfixed in M11.2.

---

#### Introduction

Here I give a re-implementation of transitive reduction.  The single function `IGVertexContract` is used from IGraph/M for convenience (to contract multiple vertex sets simultaneaously). This can be re-implemented with builtins, of course.

This implementation treats these cases separately:

- If the graph is undirected, it uses the minimum spanning tree.
- If the graph is directed and acyclic, it will remove an edge $i \rightarrow j$ if there is any path longer than 1 also connecting $i$ and $j$.  Since the graph is acyclic, any such longer path cannot include $i \rightarrow j$ itself, therefore the removal of $i \rightarrow j$ won't affect it, or the transitivity structure of the graph.
- If the graph is directed and has cycles, then it will first break it into connected components, and contract these components into single vertices, thus obtaining an acyclic graph. The transitive reduction of this acyclic graph is computed.  Finally, the vertices of each component are re-added as simple cycle graphs.

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 4, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
transitiveReductionGraph[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

---

#### Testing

Here's a small test to show that the results are reasonable:

```
Table[
 With[{g = DirectedGraph[RandomGraph[{10, 20}], "Acyclic"]},
  IsomorphicGraphQ[
   TransitiveClosureGraph@transitiveReductionGraph[g],
   TransitiveClosureGraph[g]
  ]
 ], {10}]
(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)

Table[
 With[{g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, DirectedEdges -> True]},
  IsomorphicGraphQ[
   TransitiveClosureGraph@transitiveReductionGraph[g],
   TransitiveClosureGraph[g]
  ]
 ], {10}]
(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Here's another test to show that `TransitiveReductionGraph` will frequently return wrong results and is not to be trusted.

```
Table[
 With[{g = DirectedGraph[RandomGraph[{10, 20}], "Acyclic"]}, 
  EdgeCount /@ {transitiveReductionGraph[g], TransitiveReductionGraph[g]}
 ],
 {10}
]
(* {{11, 12}, {9, 12}, {10, 11}, {10, 10}, {13, 13}, {14, 14}, {11, 13}, {10, 12}, {10, 12}, {9, 12}} *)
```

---

#### The code

```
ClearAll[transitiveReductionGraph]

(* undirected *)

transitiveReductionGraph[g_?UndirectedGraphQ, opt : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  FindSpanningTree[IGUnweighted[g], opt]

(* directed acyclic *)

transitiveReductionGraph[g_?AcyclicGraphQ, opt : OptionsPattern[]] :=    
  AdjacencyGraph[
   VertexList[g],
   With[{a = Unitize@AdjacencyMatrix[g], b = AdjacencyMatrix@TransitiveClosureGraph[g]},
    (1 - Unitize[a.b]) a
   ],
   opt
  ]

(* directed non-acyclic *)

ClearAll[namedCycle]
namedCycle[{v_}] := Graph[{v}, {}]
namedCycle[verts_] := Graph[verts, DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[verts, 2, 1, {1, 1}]]

transitiveReductionGraph[g_?DirectedGraphQ, opt : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{comps = ConnectedComponents[g], gt},
   gt = transitiveReductionGraph@IGVertexContract[g, comps];
   Graph[GraphUnion @@ Prepend[namedCycle /@ comps, gt], opt]
  ]

(* other cases, e.g. mixed graphs *)
transitiveReductionGraph[g_, OptionsPattern[]] := $Failed
```

Answer (score 12):

It's a bug.

I have reported it to WRI. The case ID is **3345230**. And the Wolfram Technical Support has confirmed it as *"a known issue"*, but no workaround is given.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work for not-too-big graphs:

```
ClearAll[MyTransitiveReductionGraph];

MyTransitiveReductionGraph[g0_Graph, opt___] := 
Module[{g, vertices, edges, newedges, s, t},
g = TransitiveReductionGraph[g0];
vertices = VertexList[g];
edges = EdgeList[g];
newedges = Pick[edges,
 Table[{s, t} = List @@ x; 
  Length[FindShortestPath[EdgeDelete[g, x], s, t]] == 0, {x, 
   edges}]
 ];
Graph[vertices, newedges, opt]
];
```

For example,

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 4, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

MyTransitiveReductionGraph[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: reduction-sample]

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer @Kato. I see your `MyTransitiveReductionGraph` relies on the buggy `TransitiveReductionGraph` function. As users without knowledge of the internal logic of `TransitiveReductionGraph`, how can we be sure this is a general fix? (Or maybe you *do* know the internal logic? ;) BTW. I heard this bug will get fixed in up-coming version, let's hold our breath!

Comment: As far as I understand, TransititiveReductionGraph is buggy in the sense that some redundant edges are not deleted. So, I simply added the follow-up routine to check that every edge thus obtained is “really” needed or not. (^^)