# Hasse Diagrams from Adjacency Matrix

Tags: graphics, matrix, graphs-and-networks

Let's say I have a rather large adjacency matrix for a partial order relation. Say an 80x80 matrix. What is the best way to display Hasse diagram? I have tried AdjacencyGraph and it does a not so bad job of displaying the graph, but it is definitely not a "good" Hasse diagram. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I was successfully able to draw the graph using

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
Hasse = ShowGraph[HasseDiagram[FromAdjacencyMatrix[hasseMatrix, Type -> Directed]]]
```

after using the information from the answer @Dr.belisarius gave.

Comment: Take a look at `HasseDiagram[ ]` on the `Combinatorica` package

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/tutorial/Combinatorica.html

Comment: I have tried to use `HasseDiagram[]`, but for whatever reason it just spits `HasseDiagram[insert.graph.here]` as output. Perhaps I am not loading Combinatorica correctly?

Comment: If you work on this, sooner or later you will come across the function `TransitiveReductionGraph`.  I wanted to warn you now that that function is [known to be buggy](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83852/12). Check the link to determine whether the bug would affect your results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example (Partial order here is vertex reachability)

```
SeedRandom@42;
<< Combinatorica`
g = System`RandomGraph[{9, 7}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
g1 = System`Graph[VertexList@g, DirectedEdge @@@ EdgeList@g]; 
ShowGraph[ HasseDiagram[ MakeGraph[VertexList[g1], 
                        GraphDistance[g1, #1, #2] =!= Infinity &]], VertexNumber -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I want except I would like to feed in a matrix as the input. This is awesome, though! I wasn't able to get Mathematica to draw HasseDiagrams at all until this example. I was beginning to think it was some sort of installation malfunction, but, alas, it was user error.

Comment: @jix816 Glad to hear that. May the force ... etc