# Given a directed graph, how can I pick out pairs of points that have 1 direct path and no other paths with intervening points?

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I have a directed graph generated from pairs of points as follows

```
n = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[100]];
pt=RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, {n, 2}].RotationMatrix[45 Degree];
pt = Sort[pt, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &];
c = Table[If[(pt[[i, 2]] - pt[[j, 2]])^2 - (pt[[i, 1]] - pt[[j, 1]])^2 > 0, 1, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}];
c = UpperTriangularize[c];
g = AdjacencyGraph[c, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
```

I want to now obtain a new graph/matrix that only has ones when 2 points have a single direct path between them and no other longer paths (i.e. paths through other intermediary points). I was using the following code for this

```
l = Table[If[c[[i, j]] == 1 && Length[Flatten[FindPath[g, i, j, n]]] == 2, 1, 0], {i, n}, {j,n}];
```

but this line of code takes a very long time to run for larger sizes (350 and above). Is there a more efficient (and more importantly faster) way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `c` upper triangular, it is a [nilpotent matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix). Its degree is less than 20 (by trial and error):

```
Max@MatrixPower[c, 20]
(* 0 *)
```

The number of paths between two vertices is then given by

```
np = Sum[MatrixPower[c, k], {k, 20}];
```

To get the adjacency matrix of vertex pairs which are connected by a single path only, we can use

```
1 - Unitize[np - 1]
```

---

Update: Based on Carl Woll's suggestion, we can also do

```
result = 1 - Unitize[Total@FixedPointList[#.c &, c] - 1];
```

Comment: You can make this approach much faster by using SparseArrays, and using nesting (e.g., `FixedPoint[ c + #.c &, c, Length[c]]`) instead.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** `TransitiveReductionGraph` is much faster:

```
t1 = First[RepeatedTiming[g1 = TransitiveReductionGraph[g];]]
t2 = First[RepeatedTiming[g2 = Graph@Select[EdgeList[g], 
      Length[FindVertexIndependentPaths[g, ## & @@ #, Infinity]] == 1 &];]]
t3 = First[RepeatedTiming[g3 = AdjacencyGraph[1 -
      Unitize[Sum[MatrixPower[c, k], {k, 20}] - 1]];]]
t4 = First[RepeatedTiming[g4 = prunedGraph[g];]]
t5 = First[RepeatedTiming[g5 = AdjacencyGraph[1 - Unitize[pathCounts[c] - 1]];]]
t0 = First[RepeatedTiming[g0=AdjacencyGraph@Table[If[c[[i, j]] == 1 && 
   Length[Flatten[FindPath[g, i, j, n]]] == 2, 1, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}];]]

Equal @@ (EdgeList/@ {g0,g1, g2, g3, g4, g5})
```

> True

```
Grid[Prepend[Transpose[{{"FindPath","TransitiveReductionGraph", 
  "FindVertexIndependentPaths", "MatrixPower", "prunedGraph", "pathCounts"}, 
  {t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5}}], {"method", "RepeatedTiming"}], Dividers -> All] // TeXForm
```

$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{method} & \text{RepeatedTiming} \\
\hline
 \text{FindPath} & 2.211 \\
\hline
 \text{TransitiveReductionGraph} & 0.0023 \\
\hline
 \text{FindVertexIndependentPaths} & 0.34 \\
\hline
 \text{MatrixPower} & 0.218 \\
\hline
 \text{prunedGraph} & 0.128 \\
\hline
 \text{pathCounts} & 0.0044 \\
\hline
\end{array} $

Although all five methods posted so far give the same result, as noted by Szabolcs in a comment, `TransitiveReductionGraph` has some [yet-unfixed bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83852/12). Carl's modification of Szabolc's approach is the fastest among remaining four methods posted so far.

**Original answer:**

You can use `FindVertexIndependentPaths` combined with `Select`:

```
Select[EdgeList[g], Length[FindVertexIndependentPaths[g, ##& @@ #, ∞]] == 1&] // Length // 
 AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.474247, 358}

```
 Select[EdgeList[g], Length[FindVertexIndependentPaths[g, ##& @@ #, ∞]] == 1&] // Short
```

> {1 -> 5, 1 -> 8, 1 -> 9, 1 -> 12, 1 -> 13, 1 -> 14, <<347>>, 101 -> 105, 102 -> 103, 103 -> 104, 103 -> 105, 105 -> 106}

Comment: I am not comfortable using `TransitiveReductionGraph` because of [this bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83852/12) which has been present since the introduction of the function, reported multiple times, yet still not fixed in 11.1 ... (Otherwise great idea!)

Comment: Thank you @Szabolcs, good point.

Comment: @kglr can you tell me how `FindVertexIndependentPaths` is different from `FindPath`? the documentation isn't very clear on this. Also your code seems to give a different answer from the one I originally had...I'm not sure why

Comment: @kglr The edge list output you give is different than what I get. Could you check whether you have the right output? Also, you might want to compare my refinement of Szabolcs' answer as well.

Comment: @CarlWoll, i added `pathCounts` to the timing comparisons. Re different edge list output, it is probably because i did not set `SeedRandom` in my original post. In the updated version I used `SeedRandom[1]`.

Comment: @kglr thanks for the comparison!

Comment: @nomaanx, good question. Regarding, `FindPath` versus `FindVertexIndependentPaths` what I know is also limited to what is avaiable in docs. It seems that `FindPath` is more general (docs say it works for weighted graphs while weighted graphs is not mentioned in the list of graphs `FindVertexIndependentPaths` handles). Re _a different answer from the one I originally had_, it is probably because of a different random seed.

Answer (score 3):

*(See addendum below for a refinement of the approach suggested by @Szabolcs)*

Another idea is to delete an edge, and check if the graph distance between the vertices is still finite. This won't be as fast as using [`TransitiveReductionGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransitiveReductionGraph) as suggested by @kglr.  Here is a function to do this:

```
prunedGraph[g_] := With[{el = EdgeList[g]},
    Graph @ Pick[el, GraphDistance[EdgeDelete[g, #], Sequence @@ #]& /@ el, Infinity]
]
```

Using this function on your graph:

```
p1 = prunedGraph[g]; //AbsoluteTiming
p2 = TransitiveReductionGraph[g]; //AbsoluteTiming

IsomorphicGraphQ[p1, p2]
```

> {0.117671, Null}
>
> {0.002606, Null}
>
> True

**Addendum**

It is possible to speed up the suggested by @Szabolcs. By using nesting instead of [`MatrixPower`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPower), and making sure to work with packed arrays, we have:

```
pathCounts[am_?MatrixQ] := With[{s = Developer`ToPackedArray@am},
    FixedPoint[s + # . s &, s, Length[am]]
]
```

This approach has the advantage that we don't need to know how many terms to [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum), we just keep applying the function until the matrix doesn't change, or until we've done it enough times to know that it won't change. Compare to the approach using [`MatrixPower`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPower):

```
r1 = pathCounts[c]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Sum[MatrixPower[c, k], {k, 20}]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 == r2
```

> {0.001114, Null}
>
> {0.230795, Null}
>
> True

Using `pathCounts`, we can generate your new graph using:

```
r1 = AdjacencyGraph[1 - Unitize[pathCounts[c] - 1]]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = TransitiveReductionGraph[g]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.0021, Null}
>
> {0.0017, Null}
>
> True