# How to extract the layers as lists from a Hasse diagram?

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks

I have an adjacency matrix

```
c={{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

I am making a Hasse diagram from this

```
am = c; 
labels = Table[i, {i, n}];
g = FromAdjacencyMatrix[am, Type -> Directed];
h = HasseDiagram[SetVertexLabels[g, labels]]
ShowGraph[h, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}]
```

[image]

this image has the advantage of displaying the nodes as layers {1,2,4}, {3,5,6,7} etc. The question is whether I can extract this information from the diagram? or better yet can I get this information directly from c without having to make the diagram at all? I am trying to find the nodes which make up the longest such layer. In mathematical jargon this would be called the maximal antichain. Also, any tips on efficiency are welcome.

The typical matrix sizes that I have to handle are above 500x500 so visual inspection is not feasible.

Edit: I'm adding in an example here which doesn't give the right layers using Halmir's method

```
{{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

[image]

The output I'm getting is `{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}}`

here is another one

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

[image]

the output is `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 8}, {6, 7, 9}}`

Edit 2: counterexample to Haldir's edited method

```
{{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

[image]

the output is `<|0 -> {1}, 1 -> {2, 3, 4, 5}, 2 -> {6, 7, 8, 9}, 3 -> {10, 11}|>`

Comment: You seem to be using the obsolete  *Combinatorica* package. What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: I have recently started using 11.1 but I haven't really tried modifying this part of the code, does it make a difference to what I'm asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version using adjacency matrix:

```
FindLayers[c_?MatrixQ]:=
    Block[{trg, m, start},
        trg=TransitiveReductionGraph[AdjacencyGraph[c]];
        m = AdjacencyMatrix[trg];
        start={};
        FixedPointList[
            (If[#=!={},m[[#,All]]=0];
            Complement[Pick[VertexList[trg],Total[m],0],start=Join[start,#],#])&,{}][[2;;-3]]
    ]
```

You can use `TransitiveReductionGraph` and then compute layers:

```
SetAttributes[updateChild,HoldFirst];
SetAttributes[updateIndex,HoldFirst];

updateChild[childfunc_,child_,parent_]/; (child=!=parent):=
   If[FreeQ[childfunc[parent],child],childfunc[parent]=Append[childfunc[parent],child]];

updateIndex[childfunc_,levelfunc_,v_]:=
    Block[{d, children},
        d = levelfunc[v];
        children= childfunc[v];
        If[Length[children]>0,
        (levelfunc[#]=d + 1)&/@children;
        updateIndex[childfunc,levelfunc,#] & /@children]
    ]

FindLayers[graph_?AcyclicGraphQ] :=
  Block[{vlist,level, child},
     vlist = VertexList[graph];
     level[_]:=0;
     child[_]:={};       
     BreadthFirstScan[graph, 
        {"DiscoverVertex"->((updateChild[child,#1,#2];level[#1]=Max[#3,level[#1],level[#2]+1])&),
         "UnvisitedVertex"->((updateChild[child,#1,#2];level[#1]=Max[level[#1],level[#2]+1])&),
         "VisitedVertex"->((level[#1]=Max[level[#1],level[#2]+1];updateIndex[child,level,#1])&)}];         
     SortBy[GroupBy[vlist,level], First]
  ]

tg = TransitiveReductionGraph[AdjacencyGraph[c]];
FindLayers[tg]
```

> <|0 -> {1, 2, 4}, 1 -> {3, 5, 6, 7}, 2 -> {8, 11}, 3 -> {9, 10}, 
>    4 -> {12, 13, 14, 15}|>

Extra edges created in TransitiveReductionGraph here doesn't really matter for computing layers, but for visualization, if your graphs are acyclic, we could define the following:

```
iTransitiveReductionGraph[g_?AcyclicGraphQ, opt:OptionsPattern[]] :=

  Block[{adjA, adjB, vlist, tg},
    vlist = VertexList[g];
    tg = TransitiveClosureGraph[g];
    adjA = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
    adjB = AdjacencyMatrix[tg];
    adjA = 
    adjA SparseArray[
      ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[adjA]] - Unitize[adjA.adjB]];
    AdjacencyGraph[vlist, adjA, opt]
   ];
iTransitiveReductionGraph[g_, opt:OptionsPattern[]] := TransitiveReductionGraph[g, opt]
```

If you want to create hasse diagram like Combinatorica package:

```
xPosition[max_,m_] := Range[m]+(max-m)/2

iHasseGraph[graph_?DirectedGraphQ, opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
    Block[{layer, l, max, vcoord, tg},
        tg = iTransitiveReductionGraph[graph];
        layer = Values[FindLayers[tg]];
        l = Length/@layer;
        max=Max[Length/@layer];
        vcoord = Flatten[Table[{#,i}&/@xPosition[max,l[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[layer]}],1];
        vcoord = vcoord[[Ordering[VertexIndex[tg,#]&/@Flatten[layer,1]]]];
        Graph[tg, VertexCoordinates -> vcoord, opts]
    ]
```

For example:

```
iHasseGraph[AdjacencyGraph[c], GraphStyle -> "BasicBlue", 
 VertexSize -> .2, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[12, White] ]
```

[image]

Here's the brute force approach using output of combinatorica:

```
res = ShowGraph[h];
text = Cases[res, Text[na_, Scaled[_, {_, y_}], ___] :> {na, y}, 
   Infinity];
Values[SortBy[GroupBy[text, Extract[2] -> First], First]]
```

Comment: he first part of your answer doesn't always give the right layers, I can't put an example in the comments but can you check with some other matrices to start and confirm that it does indeed give the layers correctly?

Comment: It's better you put the example that doesn't work (maybe in op)

Comment: okay, I've put in examples in the OP

Comment: Except that [`TransitiveReductionGraph` is broken](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83852/12) since its introduction, and it still isn't fixed in Mathematica 11.2 despite multiple reports sent to support years ago (!!)  How could I trust *any* result from `TransitiveReductionGraph` (or several other functions) while this situation persists and bug reports are ignored?

Comment: @nomaanx You better be aware of this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83852/12

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for pointing this out, it had come up in another question I asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154353/given-a-directed-graph-how-can-i-pick-out-pairs-of-points-that-have-1-direct-pa). In that case there were alternate ways to check

Comment: I modified FindLayer code. I was assuming wrong conditions when I initially wrote layer code..

Comment: @halmir just found another counterexample, adding it under edit 2

Comment: @nomaan I added more check for those cases. Code get bigger though.   There should be simpler code to do this...

Comment: @halmir thanks for all the effort

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Although the function `layersF` in the original answer computes the desired result without the need for `TransitiveReductionGraph`, it may be of independent interest to construct the transitive reduction graph from an adjacency matrix. As noted by Szabolcs, the built-in `TransitiveReductionGraph` has some "known issues" that are yet to be fixed as of version 11.2.0 ([see this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83852/125).)

An alternative approach is to construct the Hasse diagram from scratch. In the following, we do this using the function `trF` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60925/125) which is an alternative implementation of the function  `` Combinatorica`TR ``  from the package `Combinatorica` used to find the transitive reduction of a matrix representing a binary relation.

```
ClearAll[trF]
trF = Module[{r = # , m = Length@#}, Table[r[[i, k]] = r[[i, k]] 
  (1 - Times @@ Unitize[{r[[i, j]], r[[j, k]], r[[i, k]], i - j, j - k, i - k}]), 
  {i, m}, {j, m}, {k, m}]; r] &;
```

An adjacency matrix `mat` and its transtive reduction `trF@mat` have the same layers:

```
And @@ (layersF @ # == layersF @ trF @ # & /@ {c1, c2, c3, c4})
```

> True

For a given adjacency matrix (`mat`), we can use `AdjacencyGraph[trF @ mat]` to get the transitive reduction graph of `AdjacencyGraph[mat]`. The function call `agF[f, options][mat]` constructs the `AdjacencyGraph` of `f[mat]`. Using `agF` with `trF` as the first argument, and adding appropriate options, gives the transitive reduction graph we need.

```
agF[f_ : Identity, o : OptionsPattern[]] := AdjacencyGraph[Join @@ layersF[#], f@#, 
   GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding",  "VertexPartition" -> ( Length /@ layersF[#])},
   o, DirectedEdges -> False, ImageSize -> 200, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
   VertexShapeFunction -> None, VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[18, Bold]] &
```

The following function rotates and reflects the `VertexCoordinates` of a graph. We will need it to get a look similar to the one produced by `Combinatorica`.

```
rotateF = SetProperty[#, VertexCoordinates -> 
  ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}] @ RotationTransform[Pi/2] @ GraphEmbedding @ #] &;
```

The function `gridF` below is just for organizing the results when the functions a `trF` and `agF` are applied to an input matrix:

```
gridF = Grid[{{"c", "trF@c"}, {Grid@#, Grid@trF@#}, 
 {"AdjacencyGraph@c", "AdjacencyGraph@trF@c"}, {rotateF@agF[]@#, rotateF@agF[trF]@#}}, 
 Dividers -> All] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
gridF @ c1
```

[image]

```
gridF @ c2
```

[image]

```
gridF @ c3
```

[image]

```
gridF @ c4
```

[image]

An example with non-default options:

```
rotateF@agF[trF, VertexShapeFunction->"Capsule", 
 GraphStyle->"DiagramGold", ImageSize -> 300] @ c2
```

[image]

**Original answer:** Find and remove source vertices using `` GraphComputation`SourceVertexList `` recursively  starting with `AdjacencyGraph@c`:

```
ClearAll[layersF, svL]
svL = GraphComputation`SourceVertexList;
layersF = Module[{ag = AdjacencyGraph @ #},   svL /@ 
   FixedPointList[Subgraph[#, Complement[VertexList @ #,  svL @ #]]&, ag]][[;;-3]]&;
```

**Examples:** For the four arrays `{c1, c2, c3, c4}` in OP:

```
layers = layersF/@{c1, c2, c3, c4};
Transpose[{{"c1","c2","c3","c4"}, Column/@layers}]// 
   Grid[#, Dividers->All, Alignment->Left]&
```

[image]

Comment: this works, thanks!

Comment: @nomaanx, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se. Please remember to  upvote (using the up triangles on the left) when you consider an answer useful :)