# How to construct the graph of nearest neighbor diagonal squares on a chessboard from BishopGraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have already found a way to generate this graph with the following:

```
Graph[Sort/@UndirectedEdge@@@Position[Outer[EuclideanDistance@##&,#,#,1],N@Sqrt@2]&@GraphEmbedding@GridGraph@{8,8}//Union]
```

but I'm wondering if there's a shorter way to do this, possibly by using

```
GraphData[{"Bishop",{8,8}}]
```

The issue is that the Bishop Graph contains all diagonal connections, including further than nearest neighbor. `TransitiveReductionGraph` is a step in the right direction, but that takes out too many edges.

Comment: I do not think that there is a well-founded method to retrieve this graph from the bishop graph. (Note that kglr's relies on a particular ordering of the adjacency matrix, which is not a property of the graph.)

Comment: As for `TransitiveReductionGraph`, it is really meaningful only for directed graphs. For an undirected graph, it would be a simple spanning tree.  You should also be aware that [TransitiveReductionGraph is still buggy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83852/12) despite multiple requests to fix it during the past 4 years.  Personally I am very frustrated with Wolfram Research's neglect of `Graph` processing functions.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Inspired by Henrik's answer, an alternative way to use `SparseArray`  to construct the adjacency matrix directly:

```
nzp[n_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, n + 2}, {n^2, n^2}] -> Join[ConstantArray[1, n - 1], {0}],
    Band[{2, n + 1}, {n^2, n^2}] -> Join[ConstantArray[1, n - 1], {0}]}, {n^2, n^2}][
  "NonzeroPositions"]

Graph[Range[8^2], UndirectedEdge @@@ nzp[8]]
```

[image]

And using the original grid layout (as suggested in Szabolcs's deleted answer):

```
Graph[Range[8^2], UndirectedEdge @@@ nzp[8], VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[Range@8, {2}]]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** If you have to work with `GraphData[{"Bishop", {8,8}}]` you can process its `AdjacencyMatrix` to delete the unwanted elements:

```
n = 8;
e = UndirectedEdge @@@ DeleteCases[
      GraphData[{"Bishop", {n, n}}, "AdjacencyMatrix"][  "NonzeroPositions"],
        {i_, j_} /; i > j || j > i + n + 2];

Graph[Range[n^2], e]
```

> same picture as above

**Original answer:**

```
AdjacencyGraph[1 - Unitize[DistanceMatrix @ Tuples[Range@8, {2}] - Sqrt[2]]]
```

[image]

Also

```
RelationGraph[Sqrt[2] == EuclideanDistance @ ## &, Tuples[Range @ 8, {2}]]
```

> same picture

```
RelationGraph[Abs[# - #2] == {1, 1} &, Tuples[Range@8, {2}]]
```

> same picture

Comment: Oh, you're right. Must have been a caching issue on my side. I'm sorry for the disturbance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method; not really short, though.

It imploys that on a grid graph, the only pairs of distinct points that are connected by precisely two paths of length 2 are precisely those that have "diagonal distance" 1. Thus, we can determine these pairs by utilizing the square of the adjacency matrix as follows:

```
n = 8;
G = GridGraph[{n, n}];
A = AdjacencyMatrix[G];
edges = SparseArray[UpperTriangularize[1 - Unitize[A.A - 2], 1]]["NonzeroPositions"];
Graph[VertexList[G], UndirectedEdge @@@ edges]
```

This does not contain any construction of a dense distance matrix, so it should scale much better for larger values of `n` (it is already 100 times faster than OP's method). Just in case OP would like to increase `n`.