# Orderless pattern matching of rule lists

Tags: pattern-matching, options

I am looking for a compact way to specify a pattern to match a rule list with `MatchQ` that allows for enumerating the rules in the rule list in an arbitrary order. E.g. given:

```
ruleList1 = {"a" -> 10, "b" -> 2.2, "c" -> "str"}
ruleList2 = {"b" -> 2.2, "c" -> "str", "a" -> 10}
```

the following pattern will match both `ruleList1` and `ruleList2`

```
MatchQ[ruleList,  {___, "a" -> _, ___, "b" -> _, ___} | {___, "b" -> _, ___, "a" -> _, ___}]
```

Can this pattern be written in a more compact form (e.g., by using `OptionsPattern[]`)?

Comment: What about sorting `ruleList` before trying pattern matching? In that case you should be able to use only the first comparison. As in `MatchQ[Sort[ruleList2], {___, "a" -> _, ___, "b" -> _, ___}]`. Having a "normal form" can simplify your work a lot.

Comment: Related (perhaps duplicate): [Patternmatching sets](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19692/89).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [OrderlessPatternSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html)

```
MatchQ[#, {OrderlessPatternSequence[___,"a" -> _, ___, "b" -> _, ___]}] & /@
   {ruleList1, ruleList2}
```

> {True, True}

```
MatchQ[#, {OrderlessPatternSequence[___,"b" -> _, ___, "a" -> _, ___]}] & /@
   {ruleList1, ruleList2}
```

> {True, True}

Answer (score 8):

*Edit: see the bottom of this answer for my proposed solution.*

Can you be sure your rule list is well formed, meaning that it is in fact a valid list of rules?  I can think of a number of ways to approach this problem if that is the case.  For example using [`Intersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Intersection.html):

```
{"a", "b"} === ruleList2[[All, 1]] ⋂ {"a", "b"}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Or using `OptionValue`:

```
2 == Length @ OptionValue[ruleList2, {"a", "b"}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

You could also sort the list Peltio suggested.  This can be done somewhat automatically by using a head with the [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Orderless.html) attribute:

```
SetAttributes[o, Orderless];

MatchQ[o @@ ruleList2, o["a" -> _, "b" -> _, ___]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

### Timings

Peltio questioned the efficiency of using `Orderless` and he was right to do so; on longer lists it is slower than the original method.  Here are comparative timings performed in version 7.  I left out the `OptionValue` method as it failed with errors; I need to look into that.

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] :=
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

rules = Rule @@@ RandomInteger[1000, {500, 2}];

{a, b} = {277, 514};

MatchQ[rules, {___, a -> _, ___, b -> _, ___} | {___, b -> _, ___, a -> _, ___}] // timeAvg
MatchQ[Sort@rules, {___, a -> _, ___, b -> _, ___}] // timeAvg
MatchQ[o @@ rules, o[a -> _, b -> _, ___]]          // timeAvg
{a, b} === rules[[All, 1]] ⋂ {a, b}                 // timeAvg

0.262

0.131

0.702

0.000093888
```

So on this sample pre-sorting cuts the time in half, whereas using `Orderless` nearly triples it.  `Intersection` however is more than three orders of magnitude faster than any of the others.

Even better and more robust (in the case that the list contains expressions other than rules) appears to be using `FilterRules` before `Intersection`:

```
{a, b} === {a, b} ⋂ FilterRules[rules, {a, b}][[All, 1]] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.000028928
> ```

### Proposed solution

Therefore, I propose using this:

```
ruleMatch[rules_List, keys_List] := 
  Union @ keys === keys ⋂ FilterRules[rules, keys][[All, 1]]
```

Example:

```
ruleMatch[#, {"a", "b"}] & /@ {ruleList1, ruleList2}
```

> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

Comment: I beat you to your second answer by a second. Ironically, my first answer was nearly identical to your second one, I just decided to not include it now, which is what saved me that second. +1.

Comment: @Leonid If I hadn't taken the time to copy the Intersection symbol... :^)

Comment: Yeah, that's life :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You mean, "If I hadn't been so obsessed with terse code..." :D

Comment: @rm-rf That ain't nevah gonna change!!

Comment: I was wondering: perhaps using `Orderless` can result in a considerable loss of performance with respect to a simple `Sort`? Because MMA would try all possible permutations, losing a lot of time. Just a hunch.

Comment: @Peltio That is possible; *Mathematica*'s pattern matching is sometimes not well optimized.  Orderless is usually fairly fast in my experience however, so this might not disappoint.  I'll run some timings later.

Comment: @Peltio looks like you're right; Intersection is a much better method; update soon.

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to explicitly wrap both a list and a pattern in an `Orderless` container:

```
ClearAll[cont];
SetAttributes[cont, Orderless];
MatchQ[cont @@ ruleList1, cont["a" -> _, "b" -> _, ___]]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Well crud, beaten by six seconds!